# People Search Cores Results Web Part + Member Of Properties

Tags: search, search-results, people-search

Trying to configure a People Search Core Results web part in SP 2010.  I've configured it to correctly return users based on the "SPS-JobTitle" and/or "SPS-Location" attributes.  I've found, however, that these attributes are not filled in consistently, so they are not reliable for me to use.  I am interested in returning users from a certain AD Group and/or Distribution list.

Is it possible to do this?  I tried using the "SPS-MemberOf" attribute, but no luck (getting no results). I am setting this up by setting the Fixed Keyword Query to something like each of the following:

SPS-MemberOf: "+My Group Here"
MemberOf: "+My Group Here"

I am not an AD Admin by any means, but I think Security Groups and Distribution Lists are different types of objects. "+My Group Here" appears to be a Distribution List, so maybe this is why it's not working?

The question is, is it possible to setup a People Search Core Results Web Part to filter based on a users membership of a Security Group and/or Distribution List?  And if so, How?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a box to hand currently, but go into to the Enterprise Search Service Application in Central Admin, then go to Metadata Properties, find SPS-MemberOf and see if it's indexed.

Comment: I don't have access to Central Admin in this particular environment.  Is it configured by "default"?  Also, assuming it is, would this give me the functionality I desire?

Comment: That's what I'm unsure so I can't check. If it's not configured that way by default you'll have to set it so it includes that property in the index. If you have a support team, you could probably put in a request to check it.

Comment: it is set as a crawled property, but not a managed property by default.

Comment: So, let's assume default settings for the sake of this question.  The comments here I think are trying to answser it, but is it possible to do what I ask in the original posting (OP)?  That is, is it possible to setup a People Search Core Results Web Part to filter based on the user being a member of an AD Group?  Does that also apply to AD Distribution lists?